# Draw order of point symbols in QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg, draw-order

I have a point shapefile that is symbolized with an svg.  The shapefile has a attribute with Y values.  I would like the points with lower Y values to draw on top of points with higher Y values.  Below is a SE link with instructions for an earlier version of QGIS that has that feaure called *Define Order*.  I do not see that as an option in v2.8.  [How to change feature draw order in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183048/how-to-change-feature-draw-order-in-qgis).

Is that feature still an option in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the answer clearly in the link you provided in your question, the answer says that this option is available from QGIS version 2.14 and above, and here is  screenshot from QGIS 2.14.11:

[image]

Here is a screenshot in 2.18.3:

[image]

You need to upgrade to the latest LTR of QGIS 2.14.12 or QGIS 2.18.3 to get this feature. It is not available in 2.8 version.

Comment: @ahmadhanb- Right, but I installed 2.8.6 ( a later version than 2.14.12) and that option as described in my post is missing (or moved) from 2.8.6.  My question is whether that option is available in 2.8.6 and if so, where is it located in the Styles dialog.

Comment: Do you mean 2.18.2?

Comment: No 2.8.6 (Wien)

Comment: No it is not available, and you need to upgrade. I updated my answer

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't  2.8.6 is the most recent build?

Comment: No. Now it is 2.14.12 for LTR and 2.18.4 for windows, but I am not sure other OS. You can check here: http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: How do I go back to the 2.14.12 LTR version?  Do I need to do an uninstall of the current version and reinstall the software?  I am new to Linux and QGIS coming from the ArcGIS/Windows world.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am not a Linux user. I am using QGIS on windows, so I cannot help you in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I appreciate the time and effort.