# Can QGIS print nested or overlapping polygons in order?

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I use MapInfo-Discover and have calculated Catchment areas for analysis. MI won’t print overlapping polygons in one table in any set order; dividing the data into 100’s of tables isn’t a solution.

Can QGIS do this?

Comment: QGIS rendering order > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183048/how-to-change-feature-draw-order-in-qgis/183305

Answer (score 1):

QGIS allows you to sort attribute tables based on any attribute. So if the polygons have a field that numbers them in the order you want the table displayed, you can sort the table by that field.