# Setting proper rendering order because offset causes odd corners for lines

Tags: qgis, line, style, order, offset

I used offset on these lines that are on top of each other. How can I make it so the red line is not interrupted by the orange?

I can put the orange under the red, but there is another corner where the opposite then would occur.

[image]

Each line segment is a new attribute. These lines are on top of each other but used offset on one of them on this section. How can I prioritise them without it affecting the whole line?

Comment: Yes they are part of attribute table. And each line segment is a new attribute. These lines are on top of eachother, but used offset on one of them on this section. How can I prioritise them without it affecting the whole line?

Answer (score 1):

Try applying the following workflow.

**Step 1.** In the attribute table define a field that will in charge of a priority of the line features

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Proceed with `Layer Properties > Control feature rendering order > Define Order` where the priority attribute will do the job

[image: step_2]

Chech references for more details

---

**References:**

- [Changing feature draw order in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183048/changing-feature-draw-order-in-qgis)
- [Docs » QGIS User Guide » 14.1.3.2. Layer rendering](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#layer-rendering)