# QGIS 3.28 - How to display overlapping OSM polygons?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, overlapping-features

With OSM Polygons, smaller poylgons may be hidden by larger polygons. In particular, it happens with LandUse polygons overlap Building polygons.

Is there any way to display consistently 'smaller' polygons on top of 'larger' polygons, in order to see them all?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Place the land use polygon layer under the building layer.

Comment: z index is for Labels I believe. Among a given layer, you can "Control feature rendering order" based on $area (descending)

Comment: Forgot to mention, yes, polygons are all int the same layers. Fortunately, I just found a good questions on this topic and posted the answer above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a good post on this issue:
[Changing feature draw order in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183048/changing-feature-draw-order-in-qgis)

using expression area($geometry)

[image]